# Switching to branches in github

Tags: git, checkout

I was working in Chale(Kamalka) branch. when git-push, it said to first set upstream to Chale(Kamalka) but when I typed code with this branch name. It gives error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

So I checkout to master branch. And now I can't go back to Chale(Kamalka)

```
$ git checkout Chale(Kamalka)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What should I do ? please help me. I want that code, I typed whole day back.
I commit the code in Chale(Kamalka). Please help me, I am afraid.

Comment: Please make sure you understand that git is not github.

Comment: And bash is not git or GitHub.

Comment: Yeah sure... @evolutionxbox

Comment: @KamalkaFernando sorry if that was a bad tone. I wasn’t meant like that

Comment: @evolutionxbox No no don't think like that. I was so afraid that my code is lost. So I include everything I used. That's it. Thank you for your concern!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape special characters with "\". In this case to checkout to Chale(Kamalka) branch try

```
$ git checkout Chale\(Kamalka\)
```

Comment: Or `'Chale(Kamalka)'` or `"Chale(Kamalka)"`

Comment: @Zurupupz there comes this error, ```chalani@Chalani MINGW64 /h/Chale/ANGULAR/Certistore1.0/certistore (master)
$ git checkout Chale\(Kamalka\)
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        certistore/src/app/student/student-dashboard/dashboardupload/dashboardupload.component.ts
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting```

Comment: @KamalkaFernando Well that means there are files in the master branch that would get lost if you checkout to the other branch. As the warning says, stash your files using `git stash`. Read more about git stash here https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash. Remember that files which are tracked will be "deleted" when checking out to branches where they are not tracked and this can take some by surprise. I recommend backing up the entire directory before doing anything.

Comment: @Zurupupz Thank you very much for answering question. I will try what you have said.